# Dúvida sobre como calcular diferença de tempo com condições especiais

Tags: javascript, jquery, data

Estou tentando apurar a diferença de tempo entre duas datas usando o [`Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/), mas preciso observar algumas condições especiais:

> **Caso 1**: Se entrar um dia no mês, já conta como "um mês inteiro". Por
>   exemplo: do dia `31/09/2015` até `01/10/2015` = **2 meses**. Num outro exemplo, de `31/07/2015` até `16/10/2015` = **4 meses**.

Neste último exemplo, pelo `Moment.js` o resultado são 2 meses (77 dias). Segue um <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/s28Lp779/1/)</kbd> que forkei do postado pelo @Orion nos comentários.

**Update 2:** Acho que agora consegui mesmo <s>resolver esta parte</s> uma gambiarra (to usando o `moment.js` e o `split`, então chamo duas vezes os mesmos valores... gambiarra isso né???) segue o <kbd>[fiddle comentado](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/s28Lp779/25/)</kbd> (não vou postar o código aqui por enquanto pra pergunta não ficar maior ainda, depois posto como resposta se não aparecer uma solução melhor/mais simples)... /update

Este acima é um cálculo, e este abaixo é outro, sem relação entre si (um não é condição do outro, são independentes, embora partam do mesmo princípio - colocar um limite mínimo de dias para ser considerado um mês).

> **Caso 2**: Para contar como mês inteiro tem que ter mais de 15 dias no
>   mês. Por exemplo: do dia `16/09/2015` até `14/10/2015` = **1 mês** (porque só entra o mês 09, já que setembro tem 31 dias e consideramos sempre o
>   dia de início e o de fim. Se fosse até 15/10/2015 seriam dois meses). Num outro exemplo, de `31/07/2015` até `13/10/2015` = `2 meses` (como não alcançaram 15 dias, nem julho nem outubro entram).

No PHP consegui com uma baita gambiarra, quebrando as datas com `explode` e fazendo trocentos `if's` pra diferenciar meses de 30, 31 e 28 dias. Como neste caso o período não passava de um ano, então funcionou. Mas aqui neste caso tem que ser no cliente (em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ou [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)), e a diferença pode ter vários anos.

O que fiz até agora foi o seguinte:

```
function result(e) // pega os dados do form
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = document.getElementById("data1").value; // INÍCIO
    var b = document.getElementById("data2").value; // FIM

    // DIFERENÇA EM DIAS DIAS DO DIA INICIAL X FINAL 

    var checkin = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    var checkout = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    var meses = checkout.diff(checkin, 'months');

    if (meses > 0) {

        $('#meses').html(meses);
    }
}
```

A saída aqui, com datas entre `10/10/2010` e `09/10/2011` é `11`, e apenas se completa um mês inteiro passa a ser `12` (em 10/10/2011).

Como posso resolver isso pra alcançar as duas lógicas (com apenas um dia, ou pelo menos 15), considerando os meses "reais" (não o mês civil - 30 dias)? Pode ser com ou sem biblioteca (o `moment.js` ou outro). Valeu desde já.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem essas regras que você colocou, mas criei um link aqui http://jsfiddle.net/71adur8e/ para que estiver com cabeça fresca montar a lógica.

Comment: Valeu @Orion, esqueci de criar o fiddle! Então, a lógica é simples, mas como os casos ficaram juntos numa só citação acho que ficou confuso mesmo. É que são dois casos diferentes: num cálculo, preciso considerar um mês mesmo que tenha só um dia. No outro, precisa ter no mínimo 15 dias. Vou editar a pergunta. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: @ Orion, acho que encontrei uma forma de resolver o primeiro caso (mais ou menos do mesmo jeito que fiz em php) usando o `split`. Dá uma olhada > http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/s28Lp779/11/. Ainda não testei largamente, mas pelos testes aqui acho que tá ok. Agora a segunda parte precisa considerar os meses de 31 dias e tal (pra ver se deu 15), então to vendo aqui agora...

Comment: Nah, esquece, ainda não tá certo não... vou ter que botar mais uns `ifs` ... rsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seguinte, segue uma possibilidade:

No caso1 é bem simples, basta subtrair o mês de inicio do mês de termino e somar 1. Ja o caso 2 é necessario saber quantos dias tem o mês de inicio, mas existe um trick no JavaScript para saber este valor.

```js
var dataInicio = document.getElementById("dataInicio");
var dataTermino = document.getElementById("dataTermino");
var caso1 = document.getElementById("caso1");
var caso2 = document.getElementById("caso2");

var onInputChange = function (event) {
  var datas = {
    Inicio: new Date(dataInicio.value),
    Termino: new Date(dataTermino.value),
  }
  //verificando se ambas as datas são validas e a data de termino é posterior a de inicio.
  if (!isNaN(datas.Inicio) && !isNaN(datas.Termino) && datas.Termino > datas.Inicio) {
    var dtInicio = { 
      dia: datas.Inicio.getUTCDate(), 
      mes: datas.Inicio.getUTCMonth(),
      ano: datas.Inicio.getUTCFullYear()
    };
    var dtTermino = { 
      dia: datas.Termino.getUTCDate(), 
      mes: datas.Termino.getUTCMonth(),
      ano: datas.Termino.getUTCFullYear()
    };        
    dtInicio.totalDias = new Date(dtInicio.ano, dtInicio.mes + 1, 0);
    
    var qtdMesesCaso1 = dtTermino.mes - dtInicio.mes  + 1;
    qtdMesesCaso1 += (dtTermino.ano - dtInicio.ano) * 12
    
    var qtdMesesCaso2 = qtdMesesCaso1;
    if (dtInicio.totalDias < dtInicio.dia + 15)
      qtdMesesCaso2--;
    if (dtTermino.dia < 15)
      qtdMesesCaso2--;

    caso1.textContent = qtdMesesCaso1 + " Meses";
    caso2.textContent = qtdMesesCaso2 + " Meses";
  } else {
    caso1.textContent = "";
    caso2.textContent = "";
  }

}

dataInicio.addEventListener("change", onInputChange);
dataTermino.addEventListener("change", onInputChange);
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Data Inicio:
        <input id="dataInicio" type="date" />
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Data Termino:
        <input id="dataTermino" type="date" />
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    Caso 1: <span id="caso1"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Caso 2: <span id="caso2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Valeu cara, parece bem simples... mas ainda tô aprendendo javascript, então to tentando entender o código aqui... Vou tentar criar um fiddle com ele pra testar... vi que você usou o `input=time`, mas preciso usar como `text`. É compatível? E no caso 1 vc falou que precisa só subtrair o mês inicial do final e somar + 1, mas isso no código que to trabalhando só dá certo se os anos são iguais. No seu código ele soma os meses dos anos anteriores? Se der dá uma olhada neste [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/s28Lp779/25/)...

Comment: Não entendi essas variáveis `caso 1` e `caso 2`... eu não tenho nada o que pegar pra elas no form. As datas são comparadas e no caso 1, se tiver um dia já conta um mês (e vai esse número pra uma variável), e no caso 2 precisa ter 15 (e vai esse para outra variável), mas não tem o que pegar no form pra criar essas variáveis...

Comment: realmente não pensei no caso dos anos diferentes

Comment: Dando um pouco mais de contexto, esse cálculo é pra avaliar o direito ao seguro desemprego. Então, quando a pessoa tem 1 dia de trabalho no mês, já conta como um "mês de salário recebido" (e tem uma quantidade X para ter direito a cada vez que o seguro é pedido). Isso é pra avaliar se a pessoa tem direito. Então basta ter trabalhado um único dia no mês, pra esse mês já entrar na conta. Agora pra saber quantas parcelas a pessoa tem direito, então precisa contar de forma diferente (sim, é pra !#$%$% mesmo), e neste caso o mês só entra se nele foi trabalhado pelo menos 15 dias.

Comment: Os meses precisam ser considerados individualmente. Não importa o tempo transcorrido total, apenas cada mês individualmente considerado.

Comment: @gustavox esqueci de da um up, mas editei a resposta.